# Can I conditionally format the text color based 3 or more ranges of a column?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, kableextra, mutate

I am new to R, and have the following code working which sets the color of the text to red if the value if greater than 20, or blue if it is less than 20 (code block One below.  This is great.

But I need to do it for more than 2 ranges.  I tried with Code Block Two below but it errors out.  I know it needs work.  Can someone help?

```
#Code Block One
 library(tidyverse)
 library(kableExtra)
 #working!!  This specifies multiple rows but only with 2 values
 mtcars[1:10, 1:2] %>%
   mutate(
     car = row.names(.),
     
     
     cyl = cell_spec(cyl, "html", color = ifelse(cyl > 20, "red", "blue")),
     mpg = cell_spec(mpg, "html", color = ifelse(mpg > 20, "red", "blue"))
     
   ) %>%
   select(car, mpg, cyl) %>%
   kbl(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
   kable_paper("striped", full_width = F)
```

```
#Code Block Two

 mtcars[1:10, 1:2] %>%
   mutate(
     car = row.names(.),
     
     cyl = cell_spec(cyl, "html", color = ifelse(cyl > 20, "red",
                              ifelse(cyl > 10, "green",
                                     ifelse(cyl > 0, "blue")),
     
   ) %>%
   select(car, mpg, cyl) %>%
   kbl(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
   kable_paper("striped", full_width = F)

 mtcars[1:10, 1:2] %>%
   mutate(
     car = row.names(.),
     
     cyl = cell_spec(cyl, "html", color = ifelse(cyl > 20, "red",
                              ifelse(cyl > 10 && cyl<=19, "green",
                                     ifelse(cyl > 0, "blue")),
     
   ) %>%
   select(car, mpg, cyl) %>%
   kbl(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
   kable_paper("striped", full_width = F)
```

This throws this error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
> "   kable_paper("striped", full_width = F)
> mtcars"

---

Please note the post here comes very close:

[Conditionally color rows in table KableExtra()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301722/conditionally-color-rows-in-table-kableextra)

But it automatically assigns the categories, whereas I need to specify the ranges of the categories for more than one column.

Comment: Your nested `ifelse` statements are missing two closed parentheses.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where -- do you mean a parentheses right before the "if else?

Answer (score 0):

In the `cyl = cell_spec` block, you have 4 open parentheses and only 2 closed.

```
 cyl = cell_spec(cyl, "html", color = ifelse(cyl > 20, "red",
                          ifelse(cyl > 10, "green",
                                 ifelse(cyl > 0, "blue")),
```

Correct it to:

```
cyl = cell_spec(cyl, "html", color = ifelse(cyl > 20, "red",
                              ifelse(cyl > 10, "green",
                                     ifelse(cyl > 0, "blue")))),
```